# apache2: how to find out why I get a 403 error?

Tags: perl, apache, mojolicious

That is from the apache error_log:

> [Mon Oct 17 17:55:42 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /index.html denied

In `/etc/apache2/vhosts.d` I've created this file:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:3000>
    DocumentRoot "/home/mm/lib/vokabeltrainer"
    ServerName localhost:3000
    <Directory "/home/mm/lib/vokabeltrainer">
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .pl
    IndexIgnore *
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*) vokabeltrainer.pl [L]
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `/etc/apache2/listen.conf` looks like this:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:3000
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:3000
```

For testing, I've modified the folder like `chmod -R 0777 /home/mm/lib/vokabeltrainer`

When I run the `vokabeltrainer.pl` (Mojolicious::Lite script) with morbo development server it works.

Has somebody a clue where I should look?

Comment: What URL are you entering in your browser? Is it `http://localhost:3000/...`?

Comment: Did you check `/home/mm/lib`, `/home/mm` and `/home`?

Comment: This seems over-complicated.  Have you tried http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Apache2FCGI ?

Comment: @Jim Garrison: yes, I tried it this way or `http://127.0.0.1:3000/...`.

Comment: @tempire: I've found this on `https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Apache-deployment`. But maybe I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @FailedDev: I've checked the apache-logs.

Comment: @sid_com: You want to be careful about the wiki; it's a free-for-all that's not monitored by the maintainers.  Stick with what's available on http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ikegami pointed out, my first problem was that I didn't consider the /home/mm/lib part of the path: the lib-directory didn't have enough rights so I had to ad the needed rights.
Then I changed the path in the shebang form /usr/local/bin/perl to /usr/bin/perl and installed Mojolicious::Lite for the /usr/bin/perl.

The last thing I had to do, was writing the url like this `http://localhost:3000/vokabeltrainer.pl/random` instead of `http://localhost:3000/random`.
(In the `Pretty "Web 2.0" URLs` at [mojo/wiki/Apache-deployment](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Apache-deployment) is shown a way to keep the short url)